# Applyfilter in HTML5 Kinetic

Tags: html, filter, kineticjs, grayscale

I was using kinetic-v4.0.0.js and my code run perfect. I now change to the new js since I cannot find the old one so as to download it, and I have many problems.
For example one of my problems is the applyfilter.
I have:

```
 image.applyFilter({
    filter: Kinetic.Filters.Grayscale,
    callback: function() {          
        layer.draw();
    }
 });
```

and I get this:

```
 Kinetic warning: Unable to apply filter. g is undefined
```

Does anyone know what would be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `applyFilter` changed in KineticJS 4.1.0 (see the [changelog](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Change-Log#v410-nov-26-2012))

> Image.applyFilter() now takes in a required filter function, optional config object, and optional callback, rather than a config object that contained these three properties.

```
image.applyFilter(Kinetic.Filters.Grayscale, null, function() {
  layer.draw();
});
```

You can also use the `setFilter` function:

```
image.setFilter(Kinetic.Filters.Grayscale);
layer.draw();
```

Or set the filter through the images `filter` property:

```
var image = new Kinetic.Image({
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  image: imageObj,
  draggable: true,
  filter: Kinetic.Filters.Grayscale,
  filterRadius: 20
});
```